# is there any solution to get solution of internal server error 500

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

i am trying to run a autocomplete function and get the data  however i am end up getting an error that is "internal server error 500"

my client side code is the below please help

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="../Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $("#txtautocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                debugger;
                var txtname = $("#txtautocomplete").val();
                alert(txtname);

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmpBYName",
                    method: "post",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ term: txtname }),
                    ContentType: "application/json;charset-utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    }, error: function (err) {
                        // alert(err.error);\

                        alert(err);

                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: You need to check the code in `EmployeeService.asmx`. Error 500 means your backend code is broken.

Comment: Put breakpoint and try catch in `GetAllEmpBYName` method and see the exception

Comment: The http status code 500 means an unhandled exception happened when your request was done. The solution depends on what caused the exception, and without any webservice logs or information, it is very unlikely others will be able to help you. You should check the server logs, if any and/or debug the webservice calls to obtain the error details.

Comment: Post your backend code please

Comment: ok let me check all of these

Comment: thanks to all for your valuable comments